# MenuItems in ToolStrip

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, powerbuilder

PowerBuilder offers a feature such that a menu item can appear in Toolbar just by adding some toolbar properties like(toolbaritemnametoolbaritemtext etc...).

Do we have similar functionality in Windows forms applications in C# such that a menuitem can also appear in toolbar without explicitly adding a ToolStrip/ToolBar control?

Answer (score 0):

In Windows Forms you need to add a `ToolStrip` control to your `Form` to display `ToolStripItems`, such as `ToolStripButtons`. The `ToolStripItems` are added to `ToolStrip.Items` collection.

In short: **no**.